# C# Extension Method Ambiguity: Is the class being extended not part of the signature?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I am having ambiguity problems with some extension methods.  I have several similar classes, and each has an extension method called "ToEntity."  If more than one of these extension methods are brought into scope, the compiler doesn't know which to use, even though it seems it would be able to discern that by checking what extended class is trying to use it.  Apparently this is not the case, but perhaps I've done something wrong?  For example:

```
// these classes both have ToEntity() extension methods which return MyEntity
MyExtendedClass1 model1 = new MyExtendedClass1();
MyExtendedClass2 model2 = new MyExtendedClass2();

MyEntity myEntity1 = model1.ToEntity(); // ambiguous... why?
```

For the last few months I've taken a shortcut around this by calling one of the methods "ToEntity2()" which is super lame, especially now that I'm adding more classes that need to have a ToEntity() extension.  Now I'm refactoring and hoping to find a better way.  So I guess my explicit questions are:

Why are these methods ambiguous instead of being differentiated by the class they extend?
What are my options for a work-around?

Update: My extension methods would be defined like this:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static MyEntity ToEntity(this MyExtendedClass1 myExtClass)
    {
        // do stuff with myExtClass
        // eventually return a MyEntity
    }

    public static MyEntity ToEntity(this MyExtendedClass2 myExtClass)
    {
        // do stuff with myExtClass
        // eventually return a MyEntity
    }
}
```

Comment: can post the extension method, at least the signature?

Comment: Please show how the extension methods are defined.  what is the "this" parameter?

Comment: Also, Im sure you checked this but... Does `MyExtendedClass1` have a public instance method called `ToEntity()`?

Comment: I'm going to assume that `MyExtendedClass1` and `MyExtendedClass2` are derived classes of `MyEntity`.. and your extension method takes an instance of `MyEntity`. Can you confirm that with some code?

Comment: I second what Jay says. Indeed, I'll bet adding that info will turn this question from one nobody can answer into one lots of people can answer easily.

Comment: Just tested - both my comment and Jays don't result in this error. The OP's code is definitely required. To that end, I am voting to close with not enough info.

Comment: I have updated to include the signatures of the extension methods.

Comment: Your code compiles fine for me.

Comment: Do MyExtendedClass1 and MyExtendedClass2 have a common base?

Comment: Same here, I cannot get it to be ambiguous without having the method signatures the same (i.e. the class type in the extension)

Comment: @Jay - Good question, no public instance method called that though.

Comment: @DaveShaw - no common base, and both extended classes as well as MyEntity are ostensibly unrelated to each other.

Comment: Clean your solution and rebuild. We don't have enough information here to diagnose the issue. If you open a new project and paste in the code you've given us here - there is no error.

Comment: In visual studio, when you have an ambiguity error, you can roll over the "red squiggly" code and the description will show you the elements in question. Can you post what it says?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  If this compiles for you, then clearly there is some other problem in my code I will need to hunt down.  It helps me quite a bit to know that, indeed, these signatures should be enough to solve the ambiguity.  In my situation it appears there may be some issues with types that have the same name in different namespaces, even though those types are fully qualified with the namespace where appropriate.  I'll keep digging, but this is very helpful to know it's not a signature issue.

Answer (score 1):

Is one of your extension methods defined on an interface?  This, for example, causes an ambiguous invocation error:

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static void A(this IComparable<int> a) { }
    public static void A(this ValueType a) { }
    public static void CallSite() { 1.A(); }
}
```

The error is:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
>   'Namespace.Ext.A(System.IComparable)' and
>   'Namespace.Ext.A(System.ValueType)'

If all the extension methods are defined on base classes, however, the ambiguity disappears.  For example:

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static void A(this Object a) { }
    public static void A(this ValueType a) { }
    public static void CallSite() { 1.A(); }
}
```

Comment: No, but that is interesting. My problem seems to have gone away (for now...), and I can't explain it. I did NOT clean and rebuild. I had cleaned and rebuilt many times over the last few months and it did nothing. I am wondering if it had something to do with one of the data types involved coming across from a web service. In any case, all the comments have been interesting. If someone wants to close this, that's fine, but note that I did do a lot of reading on extension method signatures before posting. Sorry it was a waste of your time. Resisting the down-vote would be much appreciated.